# PostgreSQL - function concat_ws(unknown, character varying, character varying) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, string-concatenation, postgresql-9.0

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT concat_ws(', ', address1, address2, address3) as address
FROM mydb."addresses"
```

But I get the following error:

> function concat_ws(unknown, character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist

I am using PostgreSQL 9.0

Comment: `concat_ws()` was introduced in Postgres 9.1 so you can use it in your [outdated and unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) version

Answer (score 0):

`concat_ws` is available from version 9.1.

I strongly recommend to update your database.

---

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=33b6711c73e96d98f9ebaf6dff73b01f)

**Version for 9.0:**

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(field), ', ')    -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT 
        unnest(                                   -- 2
            ARRAY[address1, address2, address3]   -- 1
        ) as field
    FROM address
) s
WHERE field is NOT NULL                           -- 3
```

1. Put all columns together into one array
2. `unnest()` this array. This expands the element into each row
3. filter the `NULL` values (that's what `concat_ws()` does)
4. Reaggregate and transform into the string

Comment: Added an 9.0 compatible version